# Storage pool gone after reinstallation of OS

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core, storage-spaces

I had a Windows 2012 R2 hyper-v core installed on a disk that crashed.
I had set up a storage pool with 4 disks in it.

I replaced the crashed disk and reinstalled the OS, but the storage pool is gone.

If I run `get-storagepool` all I get is

`FriendlyName   OperationalStatus    HealthStatus    IsPrimordial    IsReadOnly
------------    -----------------    ------------    ------------    ----------
Primordial      OK                   Healthy         True            False`

And if i run `get-physicaldisk`
i get the following

`FriendlyName    CanPool   OperationalStatus   HealthStatus    Usage       Size
------------     -------   -----------------   ------------    -----       ----
PhysicalDisk3    False     Unrecognized Met... Unhealthy       Unknown     4.55 TB
PhysicalDisk0    False     Unrecognized Met... Unhealthy       Unknown     3.64 TB
PhysicalDisk1    False     Unrecognized Met... Unhealthy       Unknown     2.73 TB
PhysicalDisk4    False     OK                  Healthy         Auto-Select 55.9 GB
PhysicalDisk2    False     Unrecognized Met... Unhealthy       Unknown     2.73 TB`

PhysicalDisk4 is the OS disk!

Edit:
Well i think i know what happend now, when the disk went offline i used a USB stick with the windows 10 installation media to get access to CMD just to check the status of things, i guess it then upgraded the storage pool to a windows 10 storage pool, and 2012 R2 can't read that. i have no idea if i can downgrade it somehow?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65a87303-93bb-4172-8183-f1589ddd5ffc/storage-spaces-simple-volume-error-unrecognized-configuration-reset-drive?forum=W8ITProPreRel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the evaluation version of `windows server 2016` and im now back up and running again.

Just waiting for the free `hyper v core edition` to be released.